# Format of snmpwalk instruction

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm working with SNMP and was given a command to use.  However, I'm trying to break it down into its components so I can understand if I need to change anything.  I've found documentation on pretty much everything except for the last part.

The command has this structure:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c communityname address.com .1
```

From my understanding the meaning of this structure is:

`snmpwalk` - command

`-v 2c` - specifies that the version is 2c, options are 1, 2c, 3

`-c communityname` - specifies the community name, which is like a password to an extent

`address.com` - the address of the computer in question

`.1`  - What is this ? I can't seem to find much documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man snmpwalk` and `snmpwalk -h` should give you the info you need on the various parameters.

The `.1` is the OID and it is an optional parameter to that command, and it pinpoints a point in the hierarchical SNMP MIB on the SNMP agent host. The walk will retrieve all OIDs "below" that point.

Have a read at http://www.net-snmp.org and get a SNMP book to learn about SNMP and MIBs and OIDs; but quoting from [SNMP wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol):

> SNMP itself does not define which information (which variables) a
>   managed system should offer. Rather, SNMP uses an extensible design,
>   where the available information is defined by management information
>   bases (MIBs). MIBs describe the structure of the management data of a
>   device subsystem; **they use a hierarchical namespace containing object
>   identifiers (OID). Each OID identifies a variable that can be read or
>   set via SNMP**.

EDIT: Here is image to show the OID tree with ".1" i.e. ISO just below the root.

[image]

Comment: But you still did not make it clear what ".1" is. It is the value of "iso", which is usually the root namespace (though .0 and .2 do have their own children).

Comment: @lex-li Cheers ; now have added a image that should help the questioner.